# Is it possible in Webpack to have multiple subdirectory entry points with multiple relative outputs

Tags: webpack, entry-point, multiple-entries

Is it possible to set an entry point for each child directory then outputs to a relative build folder.  The result would be a structure something like:

```
 blockholder
│
│
├── package.json
├── webpack.config.js
│
│
├── block1
│   ├── index.js
│   └── build
│           └── index.build.js
│
└── block2
    ├── index.js
    └── build
            └── index.build.js
```

Multiple folders, each with its own entry and build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to set multiple configurations within a single webpack config file.

If you use an array in your config file, all the configurations within that config will be built.

Small example:

```
module.exports = [
{
  entry: {
    block1: "./block1/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].build.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "block1/build")
  }
}, 
{
  entry: {
    block2: "./block2/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].build.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "block2/build")
  }
}]
```

On the off-chance that your configurations will be the same for every bundle, I think you could also use a single configuration, something like this:

```
module.exports =
{
  entry: {
    block1: "./block1/index.js"
    block2: "./block2/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./[name]/build/[name].build.js"
  }
}
```